# Pass table name to @Table annotation of entity at runtime Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have a next problem: I ve got a several tables in database, and  somehow i need to make a query from one of them, but only in runtime i will know the name of needed table, so is any possibility to pass table name to @Table annotation of entity in runtime? All of these tables have absolutely identical schema. The only distinction - is name (BILLING_DATA_2016_1, BILLING_DATA_2015_12 etc.). Do somebody have an idea how can i pass the name of table dynamically? Or may be some hack with Queries and Inheritance?

Comment: I think it will depend on when you can determine the table name, I'm not too sure how you can do it multiple times but you could certainly set it once using SpEL, does your application need to set the table name once or multiple times?

Comment: Unfortunately multiple times. Table names dependent on period of time which is seting up on client side, so in every new request i need to renew @Table annotation

Comment: I don't think you will be able to solve this. If you can't change the schema then consider doing the reverse of what you have proposed: create a unified DB view of all data tables (based on a union query) and map an entity to this. Query this entity using standard date operators.

Comment: @AlanHay, it seems the best variant to resolve the issue... thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try HibernateInterceptor. Place the {BILLING_DATA_PLACEHOLDER} string into your @Table annotation and just replace it on fly

```
public class HibernateInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {
@Override
    public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
          String prepedStatement = super.onPrepareStatement(sql);
          prepedStatement = prepedStatement.replaceAll("{BILLING_DATA_PLACEHOLDER}", theRealSchemaName);
          return prepedStatement;
    }
}
```

Have not tried though